# Property 'XMLSerializer' does not exist on type 'Window' in angular 6

Tags: angular, xmlserializer

How to add reference windows reference in angular 6.

I have a following code which throws the following error as Property 'XMLSerializer' does not exist on type 'Window'

```
serializeXmlNode(xmlNode) {
    if (typeof window.XMLSerializer != "undefined") {
      return (new window.XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xmlNode);
    } else if (typeof xmlNode.xml != "undefined") {
      return xmlNode.xml;
    }
    return "";
  }
```

How to add reference to windows.xmlserializer in angular 6?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the quick dirty way is to cast the window to **any**:

```
serializeXmlNode(xmlNode) {
    if (typeof **(<any>window)**.XMLSerializer != "undefined") {
        return (new **(<any>window)**.XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xmlNode);
    } else if (typeof **(<any>xmlNode)**.xml != "undefined") {
        return **(<any>xmlNode)**.xml;
    }
    return "";
}
```

I cast the xmlNode too so there are no complaints about Node not having a property called xml.

There's probably a better way to do this by adding to the Window interface but I haven't made that work.